# Papers explaining Roberts's law

Tags: reference-request, research

I was reading [this article](http://pages.stern.nyu.edu/~xgabaix/papers/pl-jep.pdf) on power laws in economics.

If you look at figure.5 on page 11, you come across an interesting note.

> Notes: Left panel: The CEO compensation is the ex ante one, including Black–Scholes value of options
>   granted. The slope is about 1/3, ***a reflection of Roberts’s law: $Pay $~$Size^b$***
>    with b ≃ 1/3. Right panel: The
>   pay–performance sensitivity (PPS) is the Jensen–Murphy measure: by how many dollars does the CEO
>   wealth change, for a given dollar change in firm value. The slope is about −2/3, so that PPS ~ Sizeb−1
>    with
>   b ≃ 1/3. The congruence between the scalings is predicted by the Edmans, Gabaix, Landier (2009) model.

I found the source of such a law on the works cited page:

> Roberts, David R. 1956. “A General Theory
>   of Executive Compensation Based on Statistically
>   Tested Propositions.” Quarterly Journal of Economics
>   70(2): 270–94.

However I am yet to find an open source document which explains the derivation of such a law.

If anyone knows of a source Id appreciate it.